# Fontd CPU usage making Mac Mail useless

Tags: macbook-pro, mail.app, performance, font-book

Macbook Pro running El Capitan. Fontd utility just started using 100% of cpu when doing anything in Mac Mail. I have researched and performed recommendations (validate fontbook  fonts, clear/restart font server) with no benefit. Fontd still taking up nearly 100% of cpu when navigating mail.

Other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the problem only occur within Mail or also with other applications (Word, Pages for instance)?

Comment: Just seems to happen only with mail. For some reason, it isn't happening today. Perhaps validating the fonts and killing/restarting the server cleaned things up. But, its a bit odd. It didn't change immediately. It was buringing cpu cycles yesterday and leaving me with the spinning ball when reading email.